# Adobe Premiere CS6 has laggy preview with high disk access but low memory use

Tags: premiere, adobe, preview, cs6

I have a video project including 40 clips, in average 2/3 minutes, at high quality (400MB /min).

If I import a single clip in the project, the video preview is fine, however, having many of them lined after each others eventually causes the video preview to lag. If I pause and give it a few seconds, the preview after resume is fine for a while then starts lagging again.

CPU usage is bellow 20%, RAM is 1.5GB used out of 6.5GB, however disk usage is high. I assume the software can't keep up loading the video fast enough due to the heavy weight.

Is there a way to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any way to smooth up the "on the fly" preview, however, from Joshjurg's suggestion, I found the procedure to "pre-render" the preview instead. This is quite time consuming since this is basically a video rendering, however once it is done, the cache will stay up and you'll only need to pre-render the frames that have been modified.

The procedure is as follow :

- Open your shortcut panel and find the lines "Define workspace entry point" and "Define Workspace exit point" *(may not be exactly those words depending on your version)*. If necessary you can add new key binds for easy access.
- Based on the previous step, mark the entry and exit on your sequence, which will be the beginning and ending of the generated cache.
- From the "Sequence" menu, click "render workspace" *(or press enter)*.

Note that if you pre-render a portion of the sequence, but start to preview before the first frame of the cached video, the software may not actually use the cache, and use on the fly rendering instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am working in Adobe Premiere CC 2018, but if memory serves you should be able to still do this in your CS6 version.

Set an out point 'O' at the end of the clips you want to preview. 
Go up to 'Sequence' in the upper left - and select 'Render In to Out'

Once they're rendered on your timeline they should play with no lag.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no "Render In to Out" function in my version of CS6, but in the 'sequence' menu I can "render the workspace" which will bake the preview.
After this, the preview is indeed fluid. For me it took 1.5x the sequence's duration to pre-render. 

However I found into the shortcuts panel "define workspace entry point" and "define workspace exit point", which then allowed me to only render a specific part of the sequence.

Comment: Also it's probably worth mentioning that if I only pre-render a part of the sequence, and start the preview *before* the beginning of the pre-rendered part, the software somehow seems to ignore the cache and keeps rendering the preview on the fly (and therefore, keeps lagging). I'll wait a little to see if someone gives a magical trick to speed up the live rendering, otherwise I'll mark your answer as accepted, since it did the job.

Comment: Consider answering your own question - particularly since your solution differs significantly from the solution I offered. 
I *think* you get a special badge for that also!